# Badges not represented as so in the privileges

Tags: bug, badges, help-center, documentation

In the ["Set Bounties" help center page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), the badges are not represented as actual "badges", but rather plain text.

Since it's not the case on the other pages, I think it's a forgotten style so I report it here :)

> [image]